# macOS, osX, SandBox Entitlement for Spotify

Tags: macos, itunes, spotify, sandbox

Now maxOS application needs to turn on sandbox option of capabilities of Project Target.
To get access of itunes so that I can get the playerState, currentTrack of iTunes

after I add a dictionary

```
    com.apple.security.scripting-targets
```

in sandbox entitlement.
then add these

> ```
> Key: <key>com.apple.iTunes</key>
> value: <string>com.apple.iTunes.library.read</string>
> value: <string>com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo</string>
> value: <string>com.apple.iTunes.playback</string>
> ```

otherwise, playerState always nil.

But I do Spotify in the same way.

> ```
> key: com.spotify.client
> value: com.spotify.client.playback
> value: com.spotify.client.PlaybackStateChanged
> ```

But somebody told me Spotify doesn't have

> <\access-group identifier = "***" />

like iTunes.sdef so that I couldn't use like iTunes did.

What can I do with this sandbox entitlement for Spotify?